# Create space between 2 bootstrap inline forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a larger gap between those two inline forms. It does not matter how many paragraphs I put between those 2 forms. The gap size does not change.

How can I increase the gap between those 2 forms? Do I have to override the form-inline class ? I would prefer an approach using bootstrap classes.

```
<div style="background: lightgreen;" class="panel-heading">test</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>
    <form style="background: #ffff00;" class="form-inline" role="form">
    test
    </form>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p>
    <form style="background: red;" class="form-inline" role="form">
    test
    </form>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a div inbetween the two forms with whatever padding you require instead of the paragraphs.

```
<div style="background: lightgreen;" class="panel-heading">test</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<p>
<form style="background: #ffff00;" class="form-inline" role="form">
test
</form>
</p>
<div class="yourpaddingincss"></div>
<p>
<form style="background: red;" class="form-inline" role="form">
test
</form>
</p>
</div>
```